# What is afterburn command for in Freelancer?

Tags: freelancer

I see in the command controlling the ship with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key saying to Afterburn.

I don't know what that is.

Comment: What type of keyboard are you using?  I'm guessing it isn't en-US?  Here is the [tab key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key).

Comment: Or are you wondering what the afterburner does?  Basically, it makes you go really fast.

Answer (score 3):

Check that your ship has a thruster installed; it's in the 4th page of equipment, with your shield. If you have one, you can hold <kbd>Tab</kbd> to zoom at 200 MPS for a little while (still slower than cruise mode's 300 MPS though). The thruster has limited charge represented by the number to the left of your health and shield bars, but it recharges pretty fast.

Comment: The base Starflier package that you start the game with includes a thruster.  Unless you explicitly sell it (or unless someone shot it off), you should always have a thruster.

Comment: @SLaks Ah. I thought I remembered that the first ship didn't have one, but I must have been thinking of some other game. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!